# maven, how to repackage 3rd party jar with it's transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to repackage 3rd party JAR such as the resulting JAR bundles all dependencies. The JAR file I want to repackage includes `/META-INF/maven/.../pom.xml`. How to do this?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: is it possible to rebundle the uber JAR file easily with single maven command line, when given just the JAR file I want to rebundle?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the resulting jar should be a runnable jar because libraries are usually not packaged with dependencies.

I would just create a new project, add the third party jar as dependency, write a short Main class that calls the required class in the third party jar and then build a fat jar.

For that, you can either use the assembly plugin (`jar-with-dependencies`) or the maven shade plugin.

Comment: No, the resulting JAR will be used as a extension library for JMeter project (actually ran by maven-jmeter-plugin). I have hard time getting the configuration right. I would like to make the project self-contained with all the necessary libraries required by jmeter, but there are tons of them transitively.

Comment: What does it help you to package all the transitive dependencies to manage the configuration? I guess the configuration is not handled in transitive dependencies.

Comment: Fat jars as dependencies are risky. You must be sure that this fat jar is the only dependency in the project and that nobody will ever add an additional dependency. Having a fat jar and a normal jar in the dependencies list kills Maven dependency mediation and can cause a lot of problems.